# How to use delayed_job with Rails on Google App Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, delayed-job

This may be more of an App Engine question than a delayed_job question. But generally, how can I keep a long-lived process running to handling the scheduling of notifications and the sending of scheduled notifications on Google App Engine?

The maintainers of active_job https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job include a script for production deploys, but this seems to stop after a few hours. Trying to figure out the best approach to ensure that the script stays running, and also that the script is able to access the logs for debugging purposes.

I believe that Google Pub/Sub is also a possibility, but I would ideally like to avoid setting up additional infrastructure for such a small project.

Comment: We have delayed jobs that run on a schedule, do their thing and then simply set their next run date/time  based on their schedule.  They often generate log records for later consumption and/or debugging. Not very exciting, but simple and it works.

Comment: Not very exciting, but that's exactly what I need. Problem is that I'm not sure how to do this on Google App Engine, which I have to use as a customer requirement.  What does your infrastructure look like?

Comment: Vanilla rails apps with either MySQL or Postgres databases. Jobs are classes kicked off by standard delay.{method} calls.  Can do whatever you want in the method including reading from or writing to the Google Application Engine I imagine.  We use our to send off emails, push files to FTP servers, etc.

Comment: All running in AWS, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

For running long processes that last for hours, App Engine will not be the ideal solution, since the requests are cap to 60 s (GAE Standard) and 60 m (GAE Flex).

The best would be to use a Compute Engine based solution, since the you would be able to keep the GCE VM up for long periods.

Once you have deployed on your GCE VM a RESTful application you can use Cloud Scheduler to create an scheduled job with this command:

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http JOB --schedule=SCHEDULE --uri=APP_PATH
```

You can find more about this solution in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine)

If App Engine is required take into consideration the mentioned maximum request times. And additionally you can give a look to [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview), since those fit pretty much into your requirement.